All-pay auction
I am tasked with using the Revenue equivalence theorem to find the solution to the all-pay auction with $N$ players and $v_i \sim^{iid} U[0,1]$ values.
I understand the solution can be found as
$$
\beta(v_i) = F^{N-1}(v_i)v_i - \int_0^{v_i}F(z)dz = \frac{N-1}{N}v_i^N
$$
but I don't understand how the theorem is helpful in figuring this out.

Do you know the statement of the Revenue Equivalence theorem? If yes, could you please edit it into to your question?
